# Java/Android: Validating the range of acceptable values for a decimal Edit Text

Tags: java, android

In the code below,  when the minimum is set to `5.0` and the maximum to `10.0` , the Edit Text will only allow values between `5.0` and `9.9` rather than `5.0` and `10.0`. I understand that if the minimum is not `1.0` then the code will ignore all values starting with `1`.

```
etTBS = findViewById(R.id.TBS);
InputFilterMinMax limitFilterTBS = new InputFilterMinMax((float) 5.00, (float) 10.00);
etTBS.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{ limitFilterTBS});
```

.

```
public class InputFilterMinMax implements InputFilter {

private float min;
private float max;

InputFilterMinMax(float min, float max) {
    this.min = min;
    this.max = max;
}

@Override
public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
    try {
        String stringToMatch = dest.toString() + source.toString();
        float input = Float.parseFloat(stringToMatch);

        if (isInRange(min, max, input)) {
            return null;
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    }
    return "";
}

private boolean isInRange(float min, float max, float input) {
    return (input >= min && input <= max);
}
```

So my two questions are:

- what is causing this Behaviour?
- how might one go about fixing this to allow the intended range of
  5.0 to 10.0?